# RegEx: Can't seem to match numeric strings at the beginning and at the end of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Given a string (and its variations) such as:

```
-1234567890-filename.extension-0987654321-
filename.extension-0987654321-
-1234567890-filename.extension
filename.extension
```

How do I look for the first set of digits (if any), the filename.extension string and the final set of digits (if any)?

I am trying this `/^(?:-(\d+)-)?(.*)(?:-(\d+)-)?$/` but it will return only two values, where the second is filename.extension-0987654321- when the final set of digits is provided.

Thank you

Comment: `(.*)` -> `(.*?)` make it non-greedy

Comment: This is great! What's the idea behind it?

Comment: See it for your self: https://regex101.com/r/aF5rX6/1 and the non-greedy version: https://regex101.com/r/aF5rX6/2

Comment: I just wanted to know why a lazy .* would solve the problem? I can't figure it out by myself

Comment: @user2949795: Since the 2nd number part is optional, the preceding greedy matching will consume all the text and match empty string for 2nd number part. Lazy will try the 2nd number part as `.*?` extends the match.gradually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex:

```
(^-[^-]+)|(^.*$)
```

Explaining on [Regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/fN3mF7/1)